# import .txt to mysql

Tags: mysql, text-files

I have a 20000 by 1000 table in .txt file. Each column is separated by a tab. I need to import this huge table (2GB) to mysql. My sql table should have 1000 attributes and 20000 records. How can I do that ? Can I import a tab delimited file to sql?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load this data with [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool (CSV or TEXT format + command line) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). The CSV format in express edition is fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) program to import data from your text file which:

> Provides a command-line interface to the LOAD DATA INFILE SQL
>   statement

Here is a link to [four examples of mysqlimport usage](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/import-and-upload-data-to-mysql-tables-using-mysqlimport/).